# spring development - with or without eclipse + checking eclipse version

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, installation, version

Several tutorials mention that you can download spring in a tarball
and install it on your computer but when I go to the springsource
site all I can see is that you can download Spring Tool Suite
which is an eclipse plugin. So my questions are:

1. What if I wanted to work from the command line or an IDE other than eclipse?
2. The packages are available for Juno 3.8.2 or Juno 3.4.2, but how can I find
   out my eclipse version? I've downloaded the most frequently downloaded version
   of eclipse which is the one for Java EE developers but when I click on the Help
   -> About entry I get:

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

which does not match the eclipse versions on the springsource site 3.8.2 or 3.4.2,
so how do I know which plugin I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out your Eclipse version by going to Help -> About Eclipse...

In the dialog that pops up, you will see something like:

> Version 4.2.2

or

> Version 3.8.2

If you downloaded the most commonly downloaded version, then you most likely have 4.2.2. The "Juno" release actually has distributions built for both 3.8.x and 4.2.x (a little complicated and confusing, I know).  So, you should be able to install the Juno version of STS and be fine no matter what which version of Juno Eclipse you have.

---

EDIT

Your question is not very clear. I thought you were asking about how to install STS, but maybe you are asking about whether or not Eclipse is necessary at all.  The answer is that of course, Eclipse is not *necessary* for Spring development, but it really is the easiest way to develop your spring apps (disclaimer, I am on the STS dev team).

There is no single way to just "downlaod the SpringFramework" because the framework is really just a very large set of jar files and their dependencies.  Any single project typically only requires a subset of them as well as requiring other third party dependencies.  For this reason, most people prefer working with a build tool like gradle or maven.

Probably the easiest way to get started w/o STS is to clone one of the sample projects from github. A list of the templates are available here:  http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/help/descriptors-3.0.xml which is obvioulsy meant to be consumed from inside of STS.  But, you can use the file to grab links to the various github projects.

Comment: Thanks, I see there are 10 buttons on the bottom of the Help -> About Eclipse... window and the 8th button is about "Eclipse Platform" and the version shows up as 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7 which presumably is the same as version 4.2.2. The question remains about whether I really need eclipse to develop a spring plugin and how come spring downlads are now only available as eclipse plugins. Thanks, Jason Posit

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The Springsource Tool Suite (STS) is not required for developing with Spring.  If the question is how you would install the STS, that's actually very easy.  In Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) or 3.8, 4.2 (Juno), click on the `Help` menu and select `Eclipse Marketplace`.  If its not in the inital screen, use the find box type spring and click go which should bring up the the STS with the version of eclipse it is for in the title.  Click install and the correct version and its dependencies will be installed for you.  Try to use the eclipse marketplace for all the plugins you install, if possible.  It makes things much simpler